# ill-formed definition error with templated structure in c++

Tags: debugging, templates, c++11, structure, derived-class

I need help understanding GCC's problem with a templated-derived-structure.

The following is the basic content of a header file called Data.hpp:

```
template <typename T> struct DataContent {

    T *ptr;  

    // more stuff would go here but has been commented out for debug
};

template <typename T> struct Data : DataContent<T> {
public: 
    uint_fast64_t N=0;

    inline Data()  {};
    inline ~Data() { delete this->ptr; };

// ****************** PROBLEM METHOD LIVES HERE *******************
    inline Data &operator= (const T &rhs) { 
        for (uint_fast32_t n=0; n<N; n++ ) this->ptr[n] = rhs; 
        return *this; 
    };
// ****************************************************************

    // more stuff would go here but has been commented out for debug    
};

template class Data<float>;
template class Data<Data<float>>;
```

The system is a Intel i5, and the build command is:

> g++-4.9 -Wall -fexceptions -march=corei7-avx -Wnon-virtual-dtor
>   -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal -Winline -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -masm=intel -g -mfma -march=corei7-avx -mavx -O3 -std=c++11 -masm=intel -g  -c

The error I get is

```
Data.hpp   error: use of deleted function ‘Data<float>& Data<float>::operator=(const Data<float>&)’
Data.hpp   note: ‘Data<float>& Data<float>::operator=(const Data<float>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
```

Any of the following actions, by themselves, makes this error go away:

1. Eliminating explicit instantiation `template class Data<Data<float>>`
2. Making Data a stand-alone structure, without use of the base structure DataContent
3. Replacing, in the problem method, `this->ptr[n]=rhs` with `this->ptr[n]=0` (**without** changing the function declaration)

Knowing all this, I'm still confused about the source of the problem.  Frankly, I just plain confused as to why it is even trying to use the function

```
Data<float>& Data<float>::operator=(const Data<float>&)
```

anyways.  I agree with the compiler that it is "ill-formed", but why it is trying to use it in the first place!?  I expect the following functions to be used

```
Data<float>& Data<float>::operator=(const float&) 
Data<Data<float>>& Data<Data<float>>::operator=(const Data<float>&)
```

but not the one it is trying.

Equally important, it's confusing as to why fix #3 would help.  Indeed, I would expect fix #3 to actually break the compilation when building the `Data<Data<float>>`  class instantance.

Can someone please help?  (BTW, fixes 1-3 are not viable solutions for end goals)

Comment: The code you've just provided does compile while the previous one doesn't; can you roll back?

Answer (score 1):

When `T = Data<float>` (in `template class Data<Data<float>>`), the compiler doesn't know how to assign to `Data<float>` because it's an ADT and not built-in type such as `float` (in `template class Data<float>` with `T = float`). The compiler tries to auto-generate a default assignment operator but fails due to a `const` member and marks the method as `delete`.

Define a `DataContent& operator=(const DataContent& rhs)`.
A compiler like `clang` might help you in these situations because it's often able to produce [clearer error messages](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64fd6532756f6aac) than GCC's.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick.  I'm not sure why GCC is so confused, but okay.   Does this mean I have to do this for all other assignment operators,  like +=?   What about non-assignment operators like +?

Comment: That depends on how your class behaves and what's expected to do: if it's a value-like class (such as `string`, `complex` and so on) then it's advisable. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) out, particularly the second answer.